# UIActivityViewController's Title and Thumbnail Not Displayed in Certain Project with UIHostingController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm currently facing a problem where both the title and thumbnail of UIActivityViewController are not being displayed when I use this controller in my current project. On the other hand, the same code results in the title and thumbnail displaying correctly when applied to a different project. The sharing functionality is working as expected - the link is shared properly - but the title and thumbnail simply do not show up. My current environment involves using SwiftUI view through UIHostingController.

Here is the code snippet:

```
Button {
    viewModel.link = URL(string:"https://www.apple.com")
    isSharePresented = true
} label: {
    Image("ic-share-top-\(isHeaderVisible ? "black" : "white")-40")
}
.font(.system(size: 18.toPt(), weight: .bold))
.foregroundColor(isHeaderVisible ? .black : .white)
.frame(width: 40.toPt(), height: 40.toPt())
.sheet(isPresented: $isSharePresented) {
    if let url = viewModel.link {
        ActivityViewController(
            activityItems: [url],
            applicationActivities: nil
        )
    }
}

struct ActivityViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var activityItems: [Any]
    var applicationActivities: [UIActivity]?
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityViewController>
    ) -> UIActivityViewController {
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: activityItems,
            applicationActivities: applicationActivities
        )
        controller.completionWithItemsHandler = { (_, _, _, _) in
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(
        _ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController,
        context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityViewController>
    ) {}
}
```

Could anyone shed some light on why the title and thumbnail are not appearing and how to correct this issue? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated!

capture:
[expect capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc8LK.jpg) /
[now capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7Pmy.jpg)

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] describing the steps to reproduce this, starting from "create a new project"? I cannot reproduce the behaviour you described.